# Binding submit handler to form in jQuery 1.7.1 returns error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take the following code:

```
$("#docUploadForm").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Simple enough so far, right? The binding is triggered inside an `init()` method that gets fired on `$(document).ready()`.

Chrome is complaining on the line that binds the submit: **`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'toLowerCase'`**

The error thrown comes from the jQuery core. If anyone is curious, the relevant call is at line 1853 in jquery-1.7.1.js: `var match = jQuery.noData[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];`

So, what do I need to do to resolve this issue?

Firebug in Firefox 9 complains about the same issue. So it's not a browser implementation problem.

Comment: Mmm, odd that this only affects Chrome. Check that your HTML tags are correctly nested and balanced.

Comment: I just updated the question to reflect that Firefox 9 is complaining about it too.

Comment: strange...could try using submit() method instead of on()

Comment: I originally was using `.submit()` and it was complaining then, switched to using `.on()` in an effort to clear this error.

Comment: are you using jquery minified or the normal version? I remember getting some weird errors once or twice with the minified version

Comment: I'm trying this, and haven't encountered problems: http://jsfiddle.net/8tEq3/2/  Perhaps you can hone in to what's different in your example.

Comment: I was originally using the minified version, switched to the full version just to see what line was throwing the exception. Both the minified and full versions throw the same error.

Comment: I ran the resulting HTMl through the W3C validator and everything passed. So no stray tags nor improperly-nested elements.

Comment: do you have duplicate ID's ... wierd that error is from trying to lowercase an object

Comment: No duplicate IDs. Ran it through the validator - which would pick up things like duplicate IDs and improperly-nested tags - and it passes validation.

Comment: Found the issue, see my answer below. Basically, don't name form fields "nodeName"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the issue.

This is for an internal web-app that utilizes a Java Content Repository. In JCR, objects are called nodes, so we refer to an object using Node Names.

Inside my form, I had a hidden input with the id of `nodeName` which was apparently causing conflict with jQuery. The line that was erroring out in jQuery was calling `elem.nodeName` which was returning the hidden input instead of the name of the DOM node it was expecting.

So lesson learned: don't give a form element an id of "nodeName", jQuery doesn't like it.

See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwdE9/) for demo.

Comment: This isn't a jQuery issue, but a DOM one. Any name of DOM0 properties cannot easily be used for the name of a form element. DOMLint can help find these problems: http://kangax.github.com/domlint/

Comment: Thank you, Dave! I used to think I had a solid grasp of the DOM but I guess I'm not as good as I thought (the developer's life story, right?) I've added DOMLint to my toolbox and will audit all my pages against it.

Comment: Yeeeech, yet another class of spurious keywords I didn't know about.